# Scheme for Chemical Potential Energy representation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, metapost

I wrote this code to schematically represent the concept of chemical potential energy. This image will be part of a representative diagram of energy transformations in a voltaic cell: chemical potential energy -> electrical energy (= eletrical work) (transducer: Lamp) -> radiant energy -> internal energy. I ask help for two tasks: 1) add transparency and improve the representation of the test tube, 2) improving the representation of the carrot (if possible). Thanks in advance.

```
\starttext

\startMPpage
picture tube, base, carrot;
path p;
pair t;
numeric xx, y;
color carrotcolor, aquaU, aquaD, tubecolor;
carrotcolor :=(235/255, 137/255, 33/255);
aquaU := (2/255, 132/255, 130/255);
aquaD := (122/255, 186/255, 122/255);
tubecolor :=(183/255, 110/255, 184/255);

%draw the essay tube
draw origin--origin shifted (3cm,0cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1cm withcolor tubecolor;
draw origin--origin shifted (3cm,0cm) withpen pencircle scaled .8cm withcolor white;
fill fullcircle shifted (-0.01cm,0) xscaled .6cm yscaled .9cm withpen pencircle scaled .1cm withcolor white;
draw fullcircle shifted (-.010cm,0) xscaled .61cm yscaled .9cm withpen pencircle scaled .1cm withcolor tubecolor;
tube := currentpicture scaled .4;currentpicture:=nullpicture;

%draw the rectangle base
linejoin := mitered; linecap := butt;
fill (0,0)--(0,2cm)--(3cm,2cm)--(3cm,0)--cycle withcolor aquaD; 
draw (0,0)--(0,2cm)--(3cm,2cm)--(3cm,0)--cycle withpen pencircle scaled 1mm withcolor aquaU;
base:=currentpicture; currentpicture:=nullpicture;

% draw the carrot tubercle
p:= origin..(-.1cm,.15cm)..(-.1cm,2.15cm)..(0,2.15cm)..(.1cm,2.15cm)..(.1cm,.15cm)..cycle;
drawfill p withcolor transparent(1,.5,carrotcolor);
draw p ;

% draw the green leaves
linejoin :=mitered; linecap:=rounded;
for i=2 step .1 until 4:
t:= point i of p;
xx:=uniformdeviate( 1 )*1cm + xpart(t)-uniformdeviate( 1 )*1cm;
y:=uniformdeviate( 1.5 )*1cm + ypart(t);
draw t..(xx,y) withpen pencircle scaled 1.mm withcolor green;
endfor;
carrot := currentpicture scaled .45; currentpicture:=nullpicture;

%include all drawings
draw base;  
draw tube  rotated -135  shifted (2cm,1.5cm) ;
draw carrot rotated 45  shifted (2cm,.5cm) ;

\stopMPpage


\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You should edit the title of your question to suit and describe better the actual questions to get the proper attention to them.

Comment: I would separate the "drawing a carrot" part from this question if I were you. (And tag the carrot part to be [fun].)